# AngularJS - <button> with ng-click function works in the body, but not the navbar

Tags: angularjs

I have a page with multiple mailboxes, each with it's own folder structure, and a single search  that is supposed to search through a selected mailbox and folder and filter the displayed messages based on user-submitted keywords.

Example:

```
├── Mailbox 1
|   ├── Folder 1
|   └── Folder 2
|   └── Folder 3
|
├── Mailbox 2
|   ├── Folder 1
|   └── Folder 2
|   └── Folder 3
|
├── Mailbox 3
|   ├── Folder 1
|   └── Folder 2
|   └── Folder 3
```

If a user had selected Mailbox 3 > Folder 2, all contents of Folder 2 would be visible. They could then click "Search" and filter the contents of Folder 2 based on the search keywords.

The search button opens a modal, which contains a form. When the form is submitted, the modal closes, and the results on the page are filtered and displayed accordingly.

When the button is placed in the body of my page, everything works as expected. When the button is placed in the navbar, the selected Mailbox and Folder (in the back-end logic) are reset to Mailbox 1 with no Folder selected and the search functionality does not work. The reset happens on the click of the search button, before the form is submitted. As soon as the modal opens, it's looking for `mailbox id: 1, folder id: 0`, and there is no folder with id=0.

My guess is there is a scope issue, but I am not sure how to handle it. Code below.

Angular 1.6, Bootstrap 4.1

**app.ts:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', ... ]);

...
app.controller('HomeController', homeController, ['FileSaver', 'Blob']);
...

app.config(

    function ($routeProvider, ...) {

        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                redirectTo: '/Home'
            }).
            when('/Home', {
                templateUrl: 'spa/views/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeController'
            }).
        });
```

**Navbar (Index.html):**

```
<body ng-app="app">

    <div ng-controller="HomeController">
        <div>
            <nav class="navbar">

                ...

                <div class="navbar-nav">
                    <div class="nav-item">
                        <button ng-click="onSearchClick()">
                            <span>SEARCH</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                ...

            </nav>
        </div>


    </div> <!-- end HomeController -->



    <div ng-view>
        <!-- page content here -->
    </div>


</body>
```

**Body (home.html):**

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<!-- THIS CODE WORKS. THE FUNCTION FIRES AS EXPECTED. -->

<button ng-click="onSearchClick()">
    <span>SEARCH</span>
</button>


...
</div>
```

**Controller (HomeController.ts):**

```
var homeController = function ($scope, ...) {
    var vm = new HomeViewModel();
    $scope.vm = vm;

    ...

    $scope.onSearchClick = function () {
            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'spa/views/search.html',
                controller: 'SearchController',
                size: 'lg',
                scope: $scope
            });

            modalInstance.result.then(function (modalScope) {
                vm.areResultsFromSearch = true;
                vm.currentMessagePage = 1;
                getMessagesByPage();
            }).catch(() => { });
        },
            function (error) {
                vm.error = error.statusText;
            }
    }


    function getMessagesByPage() {
       // This function calls a service and then 
       // calls another function which finally displays results.
       // Much of this also depends on the HomeViewModel.
       // I don't believe any of this code is relevant here because, 
       // as I said, the code itself all works when the element 
       // is placed in home.html instead of index.html.
       // You can see why it would be difficult to, say,
       // turn this whole thing into it's own service and then use 
       // a Header Controller separate from a Home Controller. 
       // It would be major surgery on the whole application.        
    }
}
```

Comment: Is navbar a child of home? Why does it have body tags?

Comment: I'm confused as to why you have created routes and an `ng-view` element, but your home controller also controls the nav bar?

Comment: Likely you need to pass the `onSearchClick` method to navbar.

Comment: @mhatch Body encompasses the entire application. I use <ng-view> to plop the guts of the application under the <nav>, all within body. I thought that was best-practice way to do things.

Comment: @Pop-A-Stash  When I inherited this code, the navbar was wrapped in it's own "header" controller. While I redesign the app, I needed to have HomeController functions (like onSearch) available to elements in the navbar, so I felt it was just easier to wrap it in HomeController. Is this not the appropriate way to do things? I'm still pretty green with AngularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution - someone on reddit mentioned this to me a while ago for a diff issue and I completely forgot abot it!

I changed my onClick function to:

```
 $rootScope.onSearchClick = function () { ... }
```

And voila!